Google Sheets lambda or match() function?
I'm struggling with formula.. I want to sum in column K, when code in column H match code in column J. I thought I'd try a pivot table, but again something didn't work properly..?
Google Sheet example
Picture of example what I need

I tried lambda and sum.. but it's not working as it should.. any ideas?

Are GY2 (row 824) and YKD (row 834) no-stocks part of 7DL (row 808) so that the overheights sum output is 84 or it just needs to be 60 by only taking 7DL into consideration?!

Remove all of the manual entries from column K and add this to cell K2:
=LET(array,arrayformula(split(transpose(split(TEXTJOIN(",",false,MAP(H12:H1580,LAMBDA(q,iferror(if(value(q)="","",q),"|"&q)))),"|")),",")),MAP(J2:J131,LAMBDA(k,iferror(sum(FILTER(array,INDEX(array,,1)=k))))))

If there isn't a corresponding match to column J in column H, it reflects a blank cell.

You may try the following formula-
=LET(t,SCAN("",H2:H,LAMBDA(a,x,IF(ISNUMBER(--x),a,x))),
MAP(J2:J,LAMBDA(j,IF(j<>"",IFERROR(SUM(INDEX(--QUERY(FILTER(H2:H,t=j),"offset 1"))),0)))))


